# How to create kafka event from database?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, scheduled-tasks, legacy

There is a legacy service that writes values to the database.
I need to converting values to events and then sending it to kafka.

I'm going to make a service that, once in a fixed delay checks for new records and sends them, also writing the submitted records ids to the technical table, but maybe there is some other way, best practice or pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into Debezium that implements Change Data Capture on relational and NoSql data stores and streams the data into Kafka.

https://github.com/debezium/debezium

https://debezium.io/documentation